# change timezone to +08:00 in git commit

Tags: git

I tried to change the timezone for git commit.

I do some search and find this:

```
git commit --date="$(date --utc +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z)"
```

it is utc time  but I need config to GMT+08:00

I tried some option like --utc+08:00 but it's throw the bug.

```
git commit --date="$(date --utc+0800 +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z)" -am 'commit text'
date: unrecognized option '--utc+0800'
Try 'date --help' for more information.
fatal: invalid date format:
```

I know it's wrong the format date. but I can not find the solution.

Please help me do that. Thank you.

Comment: The problem lies probably in the visualization of your timestamp, not in the commit itself.

Comment: "it's not working" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: @JörgWMittag I've update the question. sorry about not clear it.

Comment: Did you try what the message says? What problems did you run into when you did?